# Script to copy range/cells value from Google Spreadsheet - paste in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for a script that can simply help me COPY a specific range in Google Spreadsheet so I can just paste it in an Excel file where this data will be processed.

The "dream" solution would be to connect and paste automatically the range from the G-Spreadsheet into the Excel file, but if there is a possibility to run a script that will "memorize" all the wanted range so I can just click "paste" in Excel - it would be a life saver!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appscript has a method [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) where you can use to copy data from one Google spreadsheet to another, but Google spreadsheet to Excel operations is not yet supported
something to that effect. What do you think?

For the meantime, you might reconsidering downloading your spreadsheet as csv so that you can open your google spreadsheet contents in Excel.

Comment: Thanks Danee, I understand that the exact thing that I wanted isn't possible so I'll check other options - thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

I would process data in Google Sheets. It's better. But if you insist...

First, write GAS code on source Google Sheet. The script executes these steps:

1. fill all unwanted area `xxx` or something.
2. save the sheet to csv file.
3. now, undo step 1.

Second, write VBA code on target Excel file. The script executes these steps:

1. open the csv file created by above GAS code.
2. read all values. You may skip `xxx`.
3. pastes those values into specific target area.

Then you just click one time in Google Sheets, and click another time in Excel and tadah! You got it.

Again, I would process data in Google Sheets.

Comment: Hey Sangbok, 

I know it'll be better to do it all in Google Sheet but unfortunately it has to be on Excel...

Since my coding skills are not really high, do you have a template of these 2 codes I need to implement?
It looks like it can be a really good solution to my problem!

Many thanks!