# Copy specific range from Google Sheets & Paste the values to excel

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

This is my first post & hello to everyone

I'm using Excel 2003 & Not a programmer - Can do some basic VBA coding.

GOAL: (Reproduce the effect of Ctrl+C from Google Sheets & Paste special - Text to Excel)

Use VBA to Copy the range "C2:E5" of a google sheet & paste it's values to range "O31:Q34" in Excel document. Using a button in Excel would be nice.

I've tried to follow several similar posts and leads:
[Script to copy range/cells value from Google Spreadsheet - paste in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018461/script-to-copy-range-cells-value-from-google-spreadsheet-paste-in-excel)

[Copy data from Google Sheet to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137298/copy-data-from-google-sheet-to-excel)

And while some were promising, it were too advance for my knowledge.
Is there any simple way to reproduce that copy/paste?
Thank you in advance.-

EDIT: The **excel file** and the **google sheet** are kept open at all times. The values of the **google sheet** change every 15 seconds or so and I manually use copy/paste to transfer them.

Answer (score 1):

First: Share your spreadsheet from google with editor mode, ie: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19285912859128591859-LIFFM/edit?usp=sharing`

Second: Edit the URL like this with "export?format and xlsx": `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19285912859128591859-LIFFM/export?format=xlsx`

Finally click in "Get Data From Web" in Excel and past that URL above. That it's all you need. If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: I make this easy for people without advanced knowledge in scripts, I wish help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I appreciate it. I edited the original post for some clarifications.  I've tried what you've suggested but when I paste the URL in the new web query window, I'm getting prompt to log in with my google account. Google won't allow me to log in as the Internet explorer used by Excel 2003 is too outdated and also get several Script errors. (I have the latest version of Internet explorer) - EDIT: Also tried on another PC with Excel 2007 and got the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you shared the spreadsheet with "everyone on the internet"? You are not supposed to need to log in with your account. Now with your "edit" the problem is clear. For now I have no clue on how to solve it for every 15 seconds.

Comment: I definitely shared the spreadsheet and while I can access it from every browser without logging in, the excel web query sends me to the log in page like I described above. Also I should note that I want to update the data manually and not automatically every 15 seconds.